# Excel VBA function to obtain positive values from a range

Tags: excel, vba

*I have this Excel VBA function:*

```
Function Positives(Rng As Range) As Range
  Dim cell As Range, out As Range

  For Each cell In Rng
    If cell > 0 Then
      If Not out Is Nothing Then
        Set out = Union(out, cell)
      Else
        Set out = cell
      End If
    End If
  Next cell
  Set Positives = out
End Function
```

*Why doesn't it work well when there are non-sequential positive numbers in Rng range? for example with values 5, 6, 7, -3, 4, 5  but values 5, 6, 7, -3, -4, -5 it works.*

*Thank you for your cooperation.*

Comment: *Why doesn't it work well* - What are the results?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for excel to display not consecutive range value using array function, see the comparison below

With consecutive range:

[image]

When it is not consecutive range

[image]

In your VBA code, when the result is in consecutive range, you will have no issue to display in array formula

[image]

When the result is not consecutive range, it return #Value as you mention, to solve this problem, one of the method is to change the result to display in string, hope you find it useful :)

```
Function Positives1(Rng As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range, out As Range, outCell As Range
Dim result As String

For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
      If Not out Is Nothing Then
        Set out = Union(out, cell)
      Else
        Set out = cell
      End If
    End If
Next cell
  
result = ""

For Each outCell In out.Cells
    If result <> "" Then
      result = result & "," & outCell.Value
    Else
      result = outCell.Value
    End If
Next

Positives1 = result
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return multiple values to multiple cells from a UDF to a sheet, you can do this using an array. Note that the best result will be when the dimensions of the call area and the return array match.

```
Option Explicit

Function Positives(Rng As Range) As Variant
  Dim cell As Range, out As Variant, i As Long

  ReDim out(1 To Rng.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)   ' form the vertical array
  For i = 1 To UBound(out, 1)
    out(i, 1) = "no value"  ' initial fill of the array
  Next
  i = 0
  For Each cell In Rng
    If cell > 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        out(i, 1) = cell
    End If
  Next cell
  Positives = out
End Function
```

[image]